# Python Launching Chromedriver from selenium works in IDLE but not Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, os.path

Below is my code and when I run it through powershell/cmd/IDLE it launches the chromedriver perfectly. However when I try to run it through visual studio code I receive the text below.

"selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home"

```
#SELENIUM INFO#
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
#SELENIUM INFO#
import os

print(os.getcwd())

driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd() +'\\chromedriver.exe')
```

I right click the code and click 'Run Python File in Terminal' However I've discovered that I can't even use the terminal to cd to the code deeper inside the file structure.

The file structure I have is "G:\Quality User Data\Malahy\Projects\AQE Interfaces>"

But the chrome driver and the python file are stored together in a deeper directory.

"G:\Quality User Data\Malahy\Projects\AQE Interfaces\AQE Interface\Logistics\Repack"

I'm starting to think this is a bug with Visual Studio Code more than my program.

Comment: sounds like you have to provide a path in your environment variables